# If a circle with a diameter of 12 contains a chord of length 6 sqrt2, what is the length of the minor arc intercepted by the chord?

Tags: geometry

I've been stuck on this question for a while now... the main problem is that I don't know the way I should draw it.

Should I draw it so that the diameter is perpendicular to the chord (so it can bisect the chord & its arc), or should I create an inscribed angle with the chord and diameter?

I tried both ways and I still have no idea how to even get an answer. Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: Thank you for your help. I finally figured it out!!

Comment: I like to draw my diameters parallel to chords. After doing this, you can draw out radii to connect the ends of the chord to the origin of the circle, and then you can do some fun triangle stuff to solve the problem.

Comment: If the chord length is $6\sqrt{2}$ and the radius is $6$, you should perhaps consider a right triangle with hypotenuse equal to the chord...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1**

What is the distance between the center of the circle and the ends of the chord (hint to hint: they're lying on the circle)?

**Hint 2**

What is the angle between the radii connecting the center of the circle and ends of the chord?

Answer (score 0):

If the radius is $r$
and the length of the chord is $ar$,
then the center
and the endpoints of the chord
form an isosceles triangle
with sides
$r, r, ar$.

By the law of cosines,
the central angle $t$ satisfies
$\cos(t)
=\dfrac{r^2+r^2-a^2r^2}{2r^2}
=\dfrac{2-a^2}{2}
$.

In this case,
$a^2 = 2$,
so
$\cos(t) = 0$
so that
$t = \pi/2$
and the length of the arc
is $rt = r\pi/2
=3\pi$
since $r = 6$.